# Excel-VBA SQL UPDATE Error "No value given for one or more required parameters"

Tags: sql, excel, sql-update, vba

I'm trying to update NUM_ID to 1 where NUM_ID is 4.

My table looks like this range A1:A6

NUM_ID
1
1
4
2
2

Excel returns error "No value given for one or more required parameters" on code below.

---

```
Sub Update()

  Dim strNUM_ID As Double
  Dim strSQL As String
  Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection

  strNUM_ID = 1

  strSQL = "UPDATE [Sheet1$] " & _
         "SET [NUM_ID] = strNUM_ID " & _
         "WHERE [NUM_ID] = 4;"

  Debug.Print strSQL

  Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
  With cnn
    .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
    .ConnectionString = "Data Source=C:\Temp" & _
        "Test.xlsm;" & _
      "Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;"
    .Open
    .Execute strSQL, DbFailOnError
  End With

  cnn.Close
  Set cnn = Nothing

End Sub
```

---

Using Excel 2010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the following line(s)

```
strSQL = "UPDATE [Sheet1$] " & _
         "SET [NUM_ID] = strNUM_ID " & _
         "WHERE [NUM_ID] = 4;"
```

to

```
strSQL = "UPDATE [Sheet1$] " & _
         "SET [NUM_ID] = " & strNUM_ID & " " & _
         "WHERE [NUM_ID] = 4;"
```